# Como iterar um atributo com reflection Java?

Tags: java, reflexão

No método abaixo, eu uso *reflection* para setar atributos de uma classe em outra, baseado em mapeamento via *annotation*. Como faço para mapear um atributo de uma classe que é atributo de outra?

Por exemplo, ao utilizar a seguinte annotation: `@Origin(field="modeloCarro.nome")` quero acessar o atributo nome do atributo `modeloCarro`.

```
/*
 * Method should be implemented for copying non homonyms fields.
 * 
 * @param T dto is the object that will receive the values.
 * 
 * @param Object obj is the original object
 */
public void toDTOMappedFields(Object dto, Object obj) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> classOriginal = (Class<?>) obj.getClass();
    Class<?> classDTO = (Class<?>) dto.getClass();

    for (Field fieldDTO : classDTO.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (fieldDTO.isAnnotationPresent(Origin.class)) {
            Origin origin = fieldDTO.getAnnotation(Origin.class);
            Field fieldOrigin = classOriginal.getDeclaredField(origin.field());
            fieldOrigin.setAccessible(true);
            fieldDTO.setAccessible(true);
            fieldDTO.set(dto, fieldOrigin.get(obj));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sendo bem direto e sem reinventar a roda. Dá uma olhada na [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

Inclusive há um método [BeanUtils.copyProperties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) que faz exatamente o que você precisa.

Tenha em mente que algum tratamento de exceção será requerido.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Conheço e estou utilizando a BeanUtils na minha solução, mas preciso de algo a mais. O método copyProperties faz a cópia de atributos com o mesmo nome. Eu implementei um método para copiar valores via annotation, agora preciso mapear atributos dentro de outros atributos conforme a pergunta.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na classe BeanToPropertyValueTransformer, deve ajudar =).

Comment: Pelo que vi realmente é o que preciso, vou ver se o comportamento do método me atende, se sim, pararei de reinventar roda haha. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o que você quer é isso, ou então algo muito parecido:

```
/*
 * Method should be implemented for copying non homonyms fields.
 * 
 * @param T dto is the object that will receive the values.
 * 
 * @param Object obj is the original object
 */
public void toDTOMappedFields(Object dto, Object obj) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field fieldDTO : dto.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (fieldDTO.isAnnotationPresent(Origin.class)) {
            Origin origin = fieldDTO.getAnnotation(Origin.class);
            String attributeRef = origin.field();
            String[] parts = attributeRef.split("\\.");
            Object ref = obj;
            for (String p : parts) {
                Field fieldOrigin = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(p);
                fieldOrigin.setAccessible(true);
                ref = fieldOrigin.get(ref);
            }
            fieldDTO.setAccessible(true);
            fieldDTO.set(dto, ref);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviamente, ainda é necessário tratar um monte de possíveis exceções, se algum campo não existir (`NoSuchFieldException`), ou se ao atravessar as referências, tiver um `null` no meio do caminho (`NullPointerException`), ou você tiver problemas com permissões de segurança no reflection (`SecurityException`), ou problemas com acesso a dados de tipos errados (`IllegalArgumentException`). O `IllegalAccessException` não deverá ocorrer nunca.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, ela é muito próxima do que preciso, assim que tiver o código com a solução postarei.